# Possible bug in scrapy 2.3.0 Invalid syntax async=False

Tags: scrapy, python-3.8

I keep getting syntax error when I'm trying to run scrapy in AWS ubuntu 18.04 instance:

```
scrapy crawl pcz -o px.csv
```

here's the log

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-60-245:~/free_proxy/free_proxy$ scrapy crawl pcz -o px.csv
2020-08-27 14:09:37 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: free_proxy)
2020-08-27 14:09:37 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 20 2020, 19:48:14) - [GCC 7.5.0], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018), cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Linux-5.3.0-1033-aws-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
2020-08-27 14:09:37 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-08-27 14:09:37 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'free_proxy',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 10,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'free_proxy.spiders',
 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408, 401],
 'RETRY_TIMES': 10,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['free_proxy.spiders']}
2020-08-27 14:09:37 [scrapy.middleware] WARNING: Disabled TelnetConsole: TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED setting is True but required twisted modules failed to import:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/telnet.py", line 15, in <module>
    from twisted.conch import manhole, telnet
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/conch/manhole.py", line 154
    def write(self, data, async=False):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2020-08-27 14:09:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Temporarily disabling observer LegacyLogObserverWrapper(<bound method PythonLoggingObserver.emit of <twisted.python.log.PythonLoggingObserver object at 0x7fe474901f10>>) due to exception: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: _findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py:153:_run_command
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:954:__del__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:261:critical
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:135:emit
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:131:__call__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:93:__call__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py:595:emit
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:154:publishToNewObserver
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_stdlib.py:115:__call__
/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:1500:log
/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:1565:_log
]

Temporarily disabling observer LegacyLogObserverWrapper(<bound method PythonLoggingObserver.emit of <twisted.python.log.PythonLoggingObserver object at 0x7fe474901f10>>) due to exception: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: _findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py:153:_run_command
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:963:__del__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:181:failure
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:135:emit
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:131:__call__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:93:__call__
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py:595:emit
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:154:publishToNewObserver
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/logger/_stdlib.py:115:__call__
/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:1500:log
/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py:1565:_log
```

]

Comment: It’s Twisted that’s failing. My guess is that you are running a version of Twisted that was not ready yet for `async` becoming a Python keyword in Python 3.5. Try upgrading Twisted.

Comment: See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143

Comment: @Gallaecio thanks, I'll check